# How to append drop-zone into data-table while button click

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new in angular 4 trying to append drop-zone on button click inside data-table row but its not initializing drop-zone may be `[config]` DOM properties not initialized with append child please someone can help

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    $("#main_datatable").DataTable({
        "ajax": 'assets/data.json',
        "columns": [{
                "data": "null",
                "defaultContent": '<button class="expansion_id" id="expansion_id"  >+</button>'
            },
            {
                "data": "firstName"
            },
            {
                "data": "lastName"
            }
        ],
        "rowCallback": (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
            const self = this;
            $(row).addClass('row_' + data.id);
            $(row).attr('id', 'row_' + data.id);
            $('td:first', row).unbind('click');
            $('td:first', row).bind('click', () => {
                self.expanded(data.id);
            });
            return row;
        },
        pageLength: 2,
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    });
}
expanded(personId) {
    var el = document.getElementById("row_" + personId);
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.setAttribute("colspan", "4");
    var file_upload = '<dropzone style="width: 100%; height: 25vh;" [config]="config"   [message]="Click or drag file here to upload" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)" (maxFilesReached)="onUploadCanceled($event)" ></dropzone>'
    td1.innerHTML = file_upload;
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    console.log(tr);
    el.after(tr);
}
```

Comment: Add some code lines so, a person who helps you will understand where you are lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure, This is possible in AngularJS or not but I have one library link for you. 
User below library, This will helps you for your needs.

[Click Here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowgroup)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.